# reCAPTCHA v.2 file_get_contents error

Tags: php, wordpress, callback, file-get-contents, recaptcha

I made custom register page on wordpress using google recaptcha. It worked fine, without any errors but when i copied a code to new project it isnt working. No clue why. No secret and sitekey errors.

```
if(!empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
{
    $gurl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $gdata = array(
        'secret' => 'secret',
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
    );

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $goptions = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($gdata),
        ),
    );
    $gcontext  = stream_context_create($goptions);
    $gresult = file_get_contents($gurl, false, $gcontext);
    var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $gresult=json_decode($gresult);
    if(!$gresult->success)
        $register_errors[]='Error reCAPTCHA.';
}
```

**UPDATE:**

output of var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) is some string propably hashed. `$gresult = file_get_contents($gurl, false, $gcontext);` is giving `FALSE` on `var_dump($gresult);`

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])?

Comment: and your get any errors message?

Comment: I updated the post. Check it please